# Problem with deleting libmysqlclient16-dev from repository of 12.04

Tags: repository

libmysqlclient16-dev deleted from Ubuntu 12.04 repository, is it possible to use libmysqlclient-dev instead of libmysqlclient16-dev or not?!! And all the features of libmysqlclient16-dev are in libmysqlclient-dev or not?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And all the features of libmysqlclient16-dev are in libmysqlclient-dev or not?!

Yes, they are.

> is it possible to use libmysqlclient-dev instead of libmysqlclient16-dev or not?!!

It should generally be possible to do that, unless your source has a hard-coded dependency upon libmysqlclient16-dev.

Note that `libmysqlclient16-dev` has been a dummy package since the days of Ubuntu 10.04, when the transition to naming the library `libmysqlclient-dev` had already been made.

Comment: Yes, i use `libmysqlclient18-dev`. But i had a problem with location of libraries, that i solved it by using `locate libmysqlclient`, and use the address that this command gave me instead. Thanks izx